# Regex match between forward slash and a dot

Tags: python, regex

I need to find any `a-zA-Z0-9` between `/` and a dot. Don't quite get how do you set non word boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to find any a-zA-Z0-9 between '/' and a dot

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/11)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.')
test_str = u"..."

re.findall(p, test_str)
```